Condition on a signature for union of substructures to be a substructure
Let $A_1,A_2 \subseteq \mathcal M$ be two substructures of a structure $\mathcal M$ with signature $S$. What is a sufficient condition on the signature $S$ that ensures the union $ A_1 \cup A_2 $ is also a substructure of $\mathcal M$?
My guess is, that if $A_1 \cap A_2$ is a substructure and the closures satisfy $\bar A \cap \bar A_2$, then $A_1 \cup A_2 $ should be a substructure. Does anyone have a reference or proof for this?
Additionally, if such a condition does not hold, how can one prove that there exists a structure and subsets that contradict this conclusion?
Thanks in advance for any help!

A necessary and sufficient condition (for the union of two substructures to always be a substructure) is that $S$ has no function symbols of arity greater than $1$.
Recall that for a structure $B$, a subset $A\subseteq B$ is the domain of a substructure if and only if $A$ is closed under all function symbols in $S$.
Suppose $S$ has no function symbols of arity greater than $1$. Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be substructures of $B$. If $c$ is a constant symbol (a function symbol of arity $0$), then $c\in A_1$ and $c\in A_2$, so $c\in A_1\cup A_2$. If $f$ is a function symbol of arity $1$ and $a\in A_1\cup A_2$, then either $a\in A_1$ or $a\in A_2$. In either case, $f(a)$ is in $A_1$ or $A_2$, since both are closed under $f$. Thus $f(a)\in A_1\cup A_2$. We've shown $A_1\cup A_2$ is a substructure of $B$.
Conversely, suppose $S$ has a function symbol $f$ of arity $n>1$. Let $B$ be the free $S$-structure on $n$ generators (i.e., the term algebra on $x_1,\dots,x_n$), let $A_1 = \langle x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\rangle$ and let $A_2 = \langle x_n\rangle$ (the substructures generated by $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ and $\{x_n\}$, respectively). Then $x_1,\dots,x_n\in A_1\cup A_2$, but $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\notin A_1\cup A_2$, since it is neither a term in $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ nor a term in $\{x_n\}$.

You wrote:

My guess is, that if $A_1 \cap A_2$ is a substructure and the closures satisfy $\bar A \cap \bar A_2$, then $A_1 \cup A_2 $ should be a substructure. Does anyone have a reference or proof for this?

I don't understand the proposal. Note that $A_1\cap A_2$ is always a substructure. And there must be a typo in "the closures satisfy $\bar A \cap \bar A_2$".

A more interesting question is whether there are conditions on a first-order theory $T$ which ensure that the substructure generated by the union of two submodels is again a model of $T$.
